# Как запретить добавлять повторные данные в словарь?

Tags: c#

Есть словарь

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

На кнопке повешан код на добавления в этот словарь какой-либо элемент

```
dictionary.Add("[Double]"), text3);
```

Если я нажму дважды на кнопку, первый раз добавлю в словарь, но при повторном нажатие получаю исключение:

> Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен.

Как сделать чтобы не добавлять повторные данные в этот словарь (в обход `try catch {}` )?

P.S: `WinForms` `net 4.5`.

Comment: ```if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(KEY)) {

     dictionary.Add()
}```

Comment: Или `dictionary[Key] = Value`. Если ключа в словаре не было - добавит, если был - обновит значение.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, Это в `if` ? Я не понял как это работает))

Comment: Эм. Какой `if`? Просто строчку свою с `Add` заменяете на аналогичную с индексатором, которую я написал ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, Спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно в core 2.0 и выше использовать

```
dictionary.TryAdd("[Double]"), text3);
```

См. описание в MSDN [Dictionary.TryAdd(TKey, TValue) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd?view=netcore-2.2)

Или, как посоветовал @Sultanov Shamil в комментариях - проверяйте перед добавлением:

```
if (!dictionary.ContainsKey("[Double]")) {
     dictionary.Add("[Double]"), text3);
}
```

Comment: А если мне нужно проверить не первый ключ, а второй text3 ? это возможно использовать так? Мне как раз нужно проверить второй ключ и из него я получаю исключения.

Comment: Кажется допёр) Это получается `ContainsValue` проверяет второй параметр да?

Comment: @Luser Да, правильно - ContainsValue (только оперируйте правильными терминами: не "первый ключ" и "второй ключ", а ключ-значение. Привыкайте к терминологии, это потом окупится многократно)

Comment: @Luser - если вам нужна коллекция без дублирования данных, то, вероятно, следует взять `HashSet` вместо словаря.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, А можно как ответ? тоже и если можно с примером)?

Comment: @Luser - Я не уверен, годится ли это для ответа. Непонятно, как и какие именно данные нужно хранить.